# I avoid interaction

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> My prefix is silence
>   My infix is a reference
>   My suffix is a direction
>   I avoid interaction

Hint #1

> My infix is the suffix of my prefix

Hint #2

> My suffix, though technically a direction, is mostly referred to be a change in direction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My prefix is silence

> tacit - understood or implied without being spoken

My infix is a reference

> it - refers to something [Edited: First try was cit. - abbreviation of citation]

My suffix is a direction

> turn - a direction, or a change in direction per hint 2

I avoid interaction

> taciturn - reserved or saying little

Comment: Correct again, Tom! But the intended infix is much simpler :)

Comment: Thank you Ébe for your lucid puzzles, I missed the simplest explanation.

Answer (score 11):

Are you a

> SHREW?

*My prefix is silence*

> SH, signalling silence.

*My infix is a reference*

> RE, meaning reference.

*My suffix is a direction*

> EW, east-west.

*I avoid interaction*

> Shrews are secretive creatures that hide away from others.

Comment: Nice answer, Rand al'Thor (+1) but the intended answer is a *lot* more straight forward. (BTW do you have a shorter reference I can call you by? :) )

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac I'm guessing your choice of the word "straightforward" in that comment is a hint, since my explanations for these clues seemed pretty simple :-) (You mean for my name? "Rand" is fine, since you're not Aiel.)

Comment: Not exactly, Rand :) Let's say if I were to correct your clarification, I would've answered a significant part of the riddle (you may take that a hint ;))

Comment: Actually @ÉbeIsaac *is* Aiel. Just look at those startling blue eyes in his profile pic. And let us not forget the prophecy: "Born of a Haskell programmer wedded to no man..."

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps

> **SHUTDOWN**

*My prefix is silence*

> "SH-" means quiet as noted by others, or "SHUT" being part of (crassly) "shut up"

*My infix is a reference*

> "-UT-" could be a reference to any number of things, including "Universal Time", "Utah", "University of Toronto", etc.

*My suffix is a direction*

> "-DOWN" is a direction

*I avoid interaction*

> To have an emotional shutdown is to cut people off; to implement a large-scale societal shutdown is to ensure minimal interaction between people

As for the hint,

> "-UT" is a suffix of "SHUT-".

Answer (score 4):

I think it might be

> Shun

My prefix is silence

> Sh

My infix is a reference

> U = reference for Uranium or possibly "you" (although this clue is very broad)

My suffix is a direction

> N for North

I avoid interaction

> Shun means to persistently avoid, ignore, or reject

Comment: Nice, but the infix is a bit too much of a stretch here.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this valid, but you could be a

> [SHUT-IN](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shut-in)

My prefix is silence

> As others have indicated, say 'SH' to silence someone

My infix is a reference

> UTI can stand for [Unique Transaction Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_Transaction_Identifier), a globally unique identifier for individual transactions in financial markets

My suffix is a direction

> N, meaning North

I avoid interaction

> A shut-in usually doesn't leave their home, thus avoiding most/all interaction

Regarding the hint

> I took that to mean there's no overlap between the prefix and infix, but I'm thinking it might actually mean the complete opposite (or something else entirely)

Comment: This is exactly the solution I just came up with, except I think the infix could be r13 (RQ vafgrnq bs RQV, ersrerapvat "rqhpngvba")

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Mummers

My prefix is silence

> To keep mum is to remain silent

My infix is a reference

> Not really sure how "me" relates here

My suffix is a direction

> R-S notation describes the direction of a molecule

I avoid interaction

> Mummers pantomime and don't interact with actual objects

Comment: Well, "me" is a good reference (a pronoun which references the speaking person).

Answer (score 1):

Could be a stretch, but I think this is

> Wraparound

My prefix is silence

> Wrap: To keep things under wraps refers to keep things secret/quiet

My infix is a reference

> APA: This is a style commonly used for references or citations

My suffix is a direction

> Around can be used as a direction

I avoid interaction

> Something that wraps around back to itself cannot interact with things besides itself.

My infix is the suffix of my prefix

> 'apa' overlaps with the 'ap' of 'wrap'

My suffix, though technically a direction, is mostly referred to be a change in direction.

> "Around" can be used as both, but is usually used for the latter

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Though your answer is not close, your suffix is much closer than the rest. Good luck!